# Interpolate (upsample) an array of data

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array of 32766 values, which I would like to upsample to fit other arrays of 65534 values.

I could also cycle in a way to take multiple times the same value, but I have to use it several times.

There is a way to increase the number of samples? I've seen the `resample` function, but it seems for a specific type of object data...

**Edit**

I was looking for the wrong term: I've found the function `interp` that upsamples for an integer number, and now I've used it and adapted the array replicating the last two values to fit the other; there is a way to automatically achieve the same size?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the same size?

Comment: @Andrey The same number of elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `interp1`:

```
  x = 1:10;
  y = x.*x;
  %The x values that you want to be interpolated; 
  xi = 1:0.25:10;
  yi = interp1(x,y,xi);
```